# Importing data from Oracle Data Pump into empty Oracle ArcSDE Geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, oracle-spatial

I have an ArcSDE Geodatabase that contains empty layers created using ArcCatalog.

I would like to import data into those layers from a **[Data Pump](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g.php)** of an Oracle database that has the same structure as the empty database.

How can I perform the spatial data import without getting problems linked to SDE?  Is it dangerous to use Oracle data import commands?  Should I use some special SDE command to perform the import correclty?

Comment: sdeexp/sdeimp is required officially for ArcSDE - there is a 'dark art' for datapumps import export - see https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10253022

Comment: I don't have access to the database of export. I only have a datapump.
What I understood from the link you provided: if the tables (from the export and the import databases) are registered as SDE tables, I can perform an "Oracle import operation" from the datapump and everything is going to work fine?!

Comment: try it on a DEV/LAB environment first

Comment: Importing from the datapump after making sure that layers are registered in both databases worked.
Thanks

Comment: It looks like you have solved your problem so would you be able to add that, with a few more details, as an Answer, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I chose is to create a dump of the source database (with the sde user) and load the dump in the target database.